# after mysql migration to postgres restarting primary key sequences and most importantly retaining older data for referential integrity aspect

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, primary-key, auto-increment

1. I migrated my mysql database to postgres and now it seems alike Sql
   server and mysql wherein we can alter datatype and apply
   autoincremet the new recorset wil get incremented values
   automatically .
2. But in postgres automatic increment-tation does not occur , there exist some tedious workaround  but retation older values is
   still a curve ball to hit
3. Is there any some linear way to retain and
       automatic apply increment primary keys values ?

Comment: it does if you make primary key field a serial .

Comment: primay key column  contains data from mysql migration will give error "serial key does not exists!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Unfortunately, currently it seems there is no direct way to achieve
  the valid migration scenario .

However, I achieved the desired result by below sql script.

```
 --create new column to create sequences
    alter table modnames add id serial; 
    ---update new column serial column with existing value
    UPDATE modnames m
    SET    id = m0.modnameid
    FROM   modnames m0
    where m.modnameid=m0.modnameid
    ---now tricky part is to tell new serial to start from max(existingid) for referential integrity
    --scenarios
    ---to figure out your serial sequence 
    SELECT adsrc FROM pg_attrdef WHERE adrelid = (SELECT oid FROM pg_class WHERE relname = 'table name goes here');
    --and apply new set of serial sequences
    Select setval('modnames_id_seq', (select max(modnameid)+1 from modname), false)
    --test you applications
    INSERT INTO public.modnames
    (mname, modnameid, createdat, updatedat, recordstate)
    VALUES('new entry set ', 0, now(), now(), 'active'::character varying);
    --to find serial sequences
    --delete old column and rename the older to new one 
    ALTER TABLE modnames RENAME COLUMN id TO modnameid;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit long for a comment.

If you are "migrating" a database from MySQL to Postgres, then you should be converting `auto_increment` columns to `serial` columns.

After moving the data over, you may need to re-start the serial value.

I don't know what process you used for moving the data, but it is possible to do it safely.

Comment: thanks @gordon linoff, apart from pgloader , is there any other open source options to fully migrate mysql tables and its content to postgres blank database , plus if primary key column contains data "serial does not exist" would come if we do that during data migration ! any suggestion , alternatives approach

Comment: @RizwanPatel . . . You might need to do pieces of the migration manually.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but No,I use an open source bi data integration tool to migrate whole db from mysql to postgres which seems about right currently since open source version for database migration wizrad for whole db migration does not seems to exists currently !